# Convert shift data to Interval-level data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a formula in column K2:Q49.
Assume my data is in the left table.

[image]

Tried multiple formulas but nothing worked. I'm also new to excel. Guess I'll need combination on excel formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SUMPRODUCT()` function:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>K2</kbd>

```
=SUM(
    (K$1 = $B$1:$H$1) *
        (
            $J2 >=
                --TEXTBEFORE(
                    $A$2:$A$3,
                    "-"
                )
        ) *
        (
            $J2 <
                --TEXTAFTER(
                    $A$2:$A$3,
                    "-"
                )
        ) * ($B$2:$H$3 = 1)
)
```

---

Formula needs to fill down and fill right!

---

From the screenshot it looks you are using older version of excel then could try the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    (K$1 = $B$1:$H$1) *
        (
            $J2 >=
                --LEFT(
                    $A$2:$A$3,
                    5
                )
        ) *
        (
            $J2 <
                --RIGHT(
                    $A$2:$A$3,
                    5
                )
        ) * ($B$2:$H$3 = 1)
)
```

---

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT((K$1 = $B$1:$H$1) *($J2 >=--LEFT($A$2:$A$3,5)) *($J2 <--RIGHT($A$2:$A$3,5)) * ($B$2:$H$3 = 1))

The formula didn't work. Result is "0" in all the cells.

Also, in future I'll have to add different shifts as well and the data in cell $B$2:$H$3 will also change. It will not be "1" always.

Comment: Formula is working as is, the screenshot clearly shows that.